# How to replicate a model 10 times and extract several objects (test results) from it, and then make a mean?

Tags: r, repeat, random-forest, spatial, dismo

excuse me my long question but I really hope that somebody could try to help me improve my code. Basically that's what I would like to do: reiterate the same model (as example random forests) 10 times with different inputs. As a result of each iteration I would like to extract from each model several parameters and after all iterations make a mean and standard deviation from them (for example mean AUC, mean bias). I may upload the input files but my problem is connected to a step that doesn't directly relies on them and I presume it may be solved using some coding. Here is an example:

I'm working with species distribution models using data from a vignette accompanying "dismo" package. All the code may be found here: https://rspatial.org/raster/sdm/6_sdm_methods.html#random-forest
First I'm creating a data of species occurences (pb=1) and pseudo-absences (pb=0). Those are accompanied by longitude and lititude cooridinates in two columns, later environmental variables are joined to each point. Everything works fine here, so I'm able to create a model. But I would like to make a several models and average their results.

These are my initial steps:

````
require(raster)
#that is my file with occurrence points:
points_herb <- read.csv("herbarium.csv",header=TRUE)
points_herb <- points_herb[,2:3]
points_herb <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = points_herb, data = points_herb, proj4string + CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
> head(points_herb)
 lon_x    lat_y
1 19.62083 49.62917
2 19.64583 49.62917
3 20.23750 49.61250...

#Variables (I use variables from PCA ran on climate)
files <- list.files("D:/variables/",pattern='asc',full.names=TRUE)
predictors <- raster::stack(files)
> predictors
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 1026, 1401, 1437426, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 16.36667, 28.04167, 42.7, 51.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      : PCA1, PCA2

#Assigning variables to points
presvals <- extract(predictors, points_herb)
reading background points (about 20000):
points_back <- read.csv("back.csv",header=TRUE,dec = ".",sep = ",")
points_back <- points_back[,2:3]
points_back <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = points_back, data = points_back, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

assigning variables to background/pseudoabsence points
absvals <- extract(predictors, points_back)
absvals <- unique(absvals)

#**this is important!** Sampling 1000 random points from my entire dataset containing ca. 20000
absvals_1 <- absvals[sample(nrow(absvals), 1000), ]

#making an input file for the modeling
pb <- c(rep(1, nrow(presvals)), rep(0, nrow(absvals_1)))
sdmdata1 <- data.frame(cbind(pb, rbind(presvals, absvals_1)))
sdmdata1 <- na.omit(sdmdata1)```

> head(sdmdata1)
  pb   PCA1    PCA2 
1  1  9.985359 2.419048 
2  1  8.711462 2.229476 
...
````

I run the model:

```
#Random Forest
library(dismo)
library(randomForest)
#rf1- first random forest model
model_rf1 <- pb ~ PCA1 + PCA2
bc <- randomForest(model_rf1, data=sdmdata1)
#the model is predicted over a geographic space
bc_mod <- predict(predictors, bc, progress='')

#let's test it using CalibratR
require(CalibratR)
#extracting model probabilities to presence and absence points (those are actually from a separate dataset)
points_pres1 <- extract(bc_mod, points_pres1, cellnumbers=TRUE)
points_abs1 <- extract(bc_mod, points_abs1, cellnumbers=TRUE)
#prepare those data to test the model 
testECE <- c(rep(1, nrow(points_pres1)), rep(0, nrow(points_abs1)))
testECE <- data.frame(cbind(testECE, rbind(points_pres1, points_abs1)))
testECE <- na.omit(testECE)
testECE <- subset(testECE, select = c(testECE, layer))
#make Expected Calibration Error
ECE <- getECE(testECE$testECE, testECE$layer, n_bins = 10)
#make Maximum Calibration Error
MCE <- getMCE(testECE$testECE, testECE$layer, n_bins = 10)
#some other test
require(Metrics)
#get RMSE values
RMSE <- rmse(testECE$testECE, testECE$layer)

random_forest_1 <- data.frame(mget(c('ECE', 'RMSE', 'MCE')))
rownames(random_forest_1) <- "random_forest1"
```

Then I would like to run the same model but using a different background points. So in that case I make another input file, with another 1000 random points from the entire dataset:

```
absvals_2 <- absvals[sample(nrow(absvals), 1000), ]
pb <- c(rep(1, nrow(presvals_2)), rep(0, nrow(absvals_2)))
sdmdata2 <- data.frame(cbind(pb, rbind(presvals_2, absvals_2)))
sdmdata2 <- na.omit(sdmdata2)

model_rf2 <- pb ~ variable1 + variable2
bc <- randomForest(model_rf2, data=sdmdata2)
bc_mod <- predict(predictors, bc, progress='')

#again, let's test it using CalibratR
points_pres2 <- extract(bc_mod, points_pres2, cellnumbers=TRUE)
points_abs2 <- extract(bc_mod, points_abs2, cellnumbers=TRUE)
# everything just as above, the objects are overwritten
testECE <- c(rep(1, nrow(points_pres2)), rep(0, nrow(points_abs2)))
testECE <- data.frame(cbind(testECE, rbind(points_pres2, points_abs2)))
testECE <- na.omit(testECE)
testECE <- subset(testECE, select = c(testECE, layer))
ECE <- getECE(testECE$testECE, testECE$layer, n_bins = 10)
MCE <- getMCE(testECE$testECE, testECE$layer, n_bins = 10)
RMSE <- rmse(testECE$testECE, testECE$layer)

random_forest_2 <- data.frame(mget(c('ECE', 'RMSE', 'MCE')))
rownames(random_forest_2) <- "random_forest2"

#And finally let's make a mean from ECE, MCE, and RMSE
rf_results <- rbind(random_forest_1, random_forest_2)
rf_results_mean <- sapply(rf_results, 2, FUN=mean)
#and standard deviation
rf_results_sd <- sapply(rf_results, 2, FUN=sd)

result <- rbind(rf_results_mean, rf_results_sd)
```

In this example a made just 2 repetitions, but ideally I would like to make a 10 or 100. How to make it more elegant and automatic rather than creating manually 100 objects..?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you look into s the tidymodels package, something like this https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/06/19/a-gentle-intro-to-tidymodels/

Answer (score 0):

Here's at least part of a solution for you using `purrr` and `dplyr` and iterating over lists. This would give the advantage of storing your samples and results in one dataframe.

In my example below I've used a randomly generated dataframe and a very simple function to demonstrate. I'll point out at the end how you might fit this to your own data and processes. I haven't tried this on your code and data above, as it's quite long and complex and would take a while to get my head around your methods. But hopefully you'll be able to see how to work this into your own process.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# step 1: create a function that takes a dataframe and returns a dataframe
calculate_mean_sd <- function(df){
  tibble(
    mean_lat = mean(df$lat),
    sd_lad = sd(df$lat),
    mean_long = mean(df$long),
    sd_long = sd(df$long)
  )
}

# random dataframe with all values you'd want to use (i.e. your `absvals` above)
full_df <- tibble(
  id = 1:100000,
  lat = runif(100000, 0, 100),
  long = runif(100000, 0, 100)
)

# step 2: create an empty list with the number (100) of loops you want to do
df <- as.list(1:100) %>% 
  map(~ tibble(iteration = .x))  # makes the iteration number into a dataframe to use later

# step 3: for each of 100 rows take a sample of a specified size and add to list as a dataframe
samples <- df %>%
  map( ~ mutate(.x, sample = list(full_df[sample(nrow(full_df), 100),])))

# step 4: iterate over list and pass your dataframes to the function, add results to new column
results <- samples %>% 
  map_df( ~ mutate(.x, results = list(bind_cols(.x[1], calculate_mean_sd(.x$sample[[1]]))))) 

# final, optional step: output a dataframe with iteration labelled and results
results$results %>% 
  reduce(bind_rows)
```

In your data above, you'd want to use `absvals[sample(nrow(absvals), 1000), ]` to sample your data in step 3, and then put the parts after this into a function which returns a dataframe with the columns you need.

This is perhaps short of giving a full answer but hopefully some helpful steps in iterating using `purrr` as a useful tool.

**Edit:** P.S. please do comment with any questions or parts that aren't working and I'll see if I can add any clarifications or notes above.